# Swagger giving Duplicate key class parameter error in Spring Boot for same Endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

For below code Swagger is giving following error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key class Parameter {
    name: Date
    in: header
    description: current date in UTC Format Ex. Thu, 25 Apr 2019 10:59:33 GMT
    required: true
    deprecated: null
    allowEmptyValue: null
    style: null
    explode: null
    allowReserved: null
    schema: class StringSchema {
        class Schema {
            type: string
            format: null
            $ref: null
            description: null
            title: null
            multipleOf: null
            maximum: null
            exclusiveMaximum: null
            minimum: null
            exclusiveMinimum: null
            maxLength: null
            minLength: null
            pattern: null
            maxItems: null
            minItems: null
            uniqueItems: null
            maxProperties: null
            minProperties: null
            required: null
            not: null
            properties: null
            additionalProperties: null
            nullable: null
            readOnly: null
            writeOnly: null
            example: null
            externalDocs: null
            deprecated: null
            discriminator: null
            xml: null
        }
    }
    examples: null
    example: null
    content: null
    $ref: null
}
```

In one of my controller I had following code, which depicts that my endpoints are having same name. Thus providing it for the reference.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/v1/{bankName}/bin")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> insProcessing(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader("mid") Long merchantId,
                                                                     @PathVariable(value = "bankName") List<String> bankName,
                                                                     @RequestParam(value = "partialDown", required = false) Integer partialDown)


@GetMapping(path = {"/v1/bin", "/v1/{bankName}/bin"}, params = {"binType"})
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> eorEmiProcessing(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader("mid") Long merchantId,
                                                                    @PathVariable(value = "bankName", required = false) String bankName,
                                                                    @RequestParam(value = "bin", required = false) String binId,
                                                                    @RequestParam(value = "binType") String binType)


@GetMapping(path ="/v1/bin", params = {"bin", "!binType"})
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> getInfo(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader("mid") int merchantId,
                                                                   @RequestParam(value = "bin") String bin,
                                                                   @RequestParam(value = "sendAdditionalParam", required = false) boolean sendAdditionalParam,
                                                                   @RequestParam(value = "issuing_bank_status",required = false) boolean issuingBankStatus)


@GetMapping(path ="/v1/bin", params = {"pageOffset", "pageNumber"})
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> getBil(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader("mid") int merchantId,
                                                        @RequestParam(value = "pageOffset", required = true) Integer pageOffset,
                                                        @RequestParam(value = "pageNumber",required = true) Integer pageNumber,
                                                        @RequestParam(value = "sendAdditionalParam", required = false) boolean sendAdditionalParam,
                                                        @RequestParam(value = "issuing_bank_status",required = false) boolean issuingBankStatus) {
```

Also the following configuration can be found at SwaggerConfig.java:

```
@Bean
  public Operation customHeader() {
    return (Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) -> {
      Parameter date = new Parameter().in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString()).schema(new StringSchema()).name("Date")
              .description("current date in UTC Format Ex. Thu, 25 Apr 2019 10:59:33 GMT").required(true);
      Parameter digest = new Parameter().in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString()).schema(new StringSchema()).name("Digest")
              .description("Base encode of ( hash of ( the json data to post to server ) )").required(true);
      Parameter authorization = new Parameter().in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString()).schema(new StringSchema()).name("Authorization")
              .description("In the \", algorithm=\"6\", headers=\"date digest\", signature=\"E4=").required(true);
      operation.addParametersItem(date);
      operation.addParametersItem(digest);
      operation.addParametersItem(authorization);
      return operation;
    };
  }
```

**Note: I have changed value for same parameters, like algorithm, signature.**

When I erase the controller having same endpoints name, everything just works fine.
So is there any way out of it without changing endpoints.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/) using mapping's **params** to have separate operations is not possible:
_OpenAPI defines a unique operation as a combination of a path and an HTTP method. This means that two GET or two POST methods for the same path are not allowed – even if they have different parameters (parameters have no effect on uniqueness)._